How can the DKW inequality be refined for the gamma distribution?
The Dvoretzky-Kiefer-Wolfowitz (DKW) inequality provides a uniform, distribution-free bound on the absolute error between the empirical CDF $\hat F_n(x)$ and the population CDF $F_n(x)$ anywhere on the support of the distribution. However, the DKW bound is often loose for specific distributions. In its generality it has to be true for even the slowest-converging cases, but I expect these bounds are overly-pessimistic for commonly-used distributions like the gamma distribution.
The gamma distribution is a worthwhile starting point for me because it is relevant in the time-to-event distributions. I study various discrete event simulations where I have noticed over time that the time-to-event distributions are usually very good fits with Gamma distributions (or special cases of it like the exponential distribution). At worst I have seen what appear to be mixtures of Gammas, but that is more ambitious than what I want to cover in this post.
For the gamma distribution $\operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$, are there tighter error tolerances available that take advantage of the properties of the gamma CDF? For instance:

Can we leverage the smoothness or tail behavior of the gamma CDF to derive tighter bounds?
Are there specific results for the gamma distribution as a special case of the DKW inequality?


How I typically go about this sort of thing is through simulation. I pick a population set of parameters, a sequence of sample sizes, and a number of replicates (e.g. in $[10^4, 10^6]$ depending on a judgement call), and then estimate said absolute errors and probabilities. These simulation studies are not hard to setup, but it would be nice to just pick a sample size and know at least a bound on what I am guaranteeing in terms of the correctness of my results. The other thing is that these simulation studies also have estimation (sampling) error in the sample sizes and tolerances anyways, inviting the meta question of how large my simulation studies for estimating sample size need to be? 

This inequality has nothing to do with the distribution.  For any given (continuous, anyway) $F$ you can always apply the PIT to reduce the situation to the uniform distribution on $[0,1].$
